# (ERROR) No Persistence provider for EntityManager named persistence

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

buenas tengo problemas al intentar persistir

mi xml es este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

<persistence-unit name="persistence">
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>gradle.cucumber.Usuario</class>

<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
</properties>
```

estoy corriendo todo con inteliJ

el xml se encuentra en la ruta: META-INF/persistence.xml
segun otros foros dicen que:  agregar el persistence.xml la ruta del archivo a compilar (pero no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo en intelij)

y tambien en mi gradle uso el  `compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.3.7.Final'`

el error completo es este:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for   EntityManager named persistence: Provider named   org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider threw unexpected exception at    create EntityManagerFactory:
```